# Implementando el patrón Specification

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy trabajando en una app Windows Forms, usando EF code first.

Tengo una regla de negocio en la entidad Proveedor y al momento de darle de alta verifico si la RazonSocial existe si existe ya no da de alta y muestra un mensaje "El proveedor que intenta registra ya existe" y si no existe da de alta al nuevo proveedor. En este caso me estoy asegurando de no tener duplicado al Proveedor.

He implementando el patrón Specification pero no se como usarlo

```
public void Create(Proveedor entity)
    {
        ValidationResult result = _proveedorValidator.Validate(entity);
        if (result.IsValid) // Con estas dos lineas hago una validación de datos
            // Valido si existe el Id para procedera a Actualizar o dar de Alta
            if (_proveedorRespository.Existe(entity.ProveedorId))
                // Procedo a Actualizar
                _proveedorRespository.Update(entity);
            else
            {   // Intento utilizar Specification
                ISpecification<Proveedor> proveedorRazonSocial =
                new ExpressionSpecification<Proveedor>(o => o.RazonSocial == entity.RazonSocial);
                if(proveedorRazonSocial)
                {
                    _proveedorRespository.Create(entity);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Mensanje: "El proveedor que intenta registra ya existe"
                }
            } 
        else
            throw new CustomException(Validator.GetErrorMessages(result.Errors));
    }
```

Implementación de Specification

And

```
public class AndSpecification<T> : CompositeSpecification<T>
{
    ISpecification<T> leftSpecification;
    ISpecification<T> rightSpecification;

    public AndSpecification(ISpecification<T> left, ISpecification<T> right)
    {
        this.leftSpecification = left;
        this.rightSpecification = right;
    }
    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(T o)
    {
        return this.leftSpecification.IsSatisfiedBy(o)
            && this.rightSpecification.IsSatisfiedBy(o);
    }
}
```

Composite

```
public abstract class CompositeSpecification<T> : ISpecification<T>
{
    public abstract bool IsSatisfiedBy(T o);
    public ISpecification<T> And(ISpecification<T> specification)
    {
        return new AndSpecification<T>(this, specification); 
    }
    public ISpecification<T> Or(ISpecification<T> specification)
    {
        return new OrSpecification<T>(this, specification);
    }
    public ISpecification<T> Not(ISpecification<T> specification)
    {
        return new NotSpecification<T>(specification);
    }
}
```

Expression

```
public class ExpressionSpecification<T> : CompositeSpecification<T>
{
    private Func<T, bool> expression;

    public ExpressionSpecification(Func<T, bool> expression)
    {
        if (expression == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        else
            this.expression = expression;
    }
    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(T o)
    {
        return this.expression(o);
    }
}
```

Interfaz

```
public interface ISpecification<T>
{
    bool IsSatisfiedBy(T o);
    ISpecification<T> And(ISpecification<T> specification);
    ISpecification<T> Or(ISpecification<T> specification);
    ISpecification<T> Not(ISpecification<T> specification);
}
```

Not

```
public class NotSpecification<T> : CompositeSpecification<T>
{
    ISpecification<T> specification;

    public NotSpecification(ISpecification<T> spec)
    {
        this.specification = spec;
    }
    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(T o)
    {
        return !this.specification.IsSatisfiedBy(o);
    }
}
```

Or

```
public class OrSpecification<T> : CompositeSpecification<T>
{
    ISpecification<T> leftSpecification;
    ISpecification<T> rightSpecification;

    public OrSpecification(ISpecification<T> left, ISpecification<T> right)
    {
        this.leftSpecification = left;
        this.rightSpecification = right;
    }
    public override bool IsSatisfiedBy(T o)
    {
        return this.leftSpecification.IsSatisfiedBy(o)
            || this.rightSpecification.IsSatisfiedBy(o);
    }
}
```

¿Como debería utilizarlo en el método Create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque te complicaste si con entity framework no necesitas ningun Specification

cuando armas el repository puedes enviar un lambda directo indicando el filtro, ese patron es simplemente para complicarte

si analiza el codigo del repository del articulo

[[Entity Framework][Code First] Crear entidad simple](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2013/06/entity-frameworkcode-first-crear.html)

veras que puedes definir `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` con esto ya indicas el lambda que aplicas como filtro

podrias crear un metodo

```
public bool Exists(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    using (NorthWindContext context = new NorthWindContext())
    {
        return context.Set<T>().Any(predicate);
    }
}
```

entonces lo usarias

```
bool exist = _proveedorRespository.Exists(o => o.RazonSocial == entity.RazonSocial)

if(exist)
{
    //Mensanje: "El proveedor que intenta registra ya existe"
    return;
}

_proveedorRespository.Create(entity);
```

Answer (score 1):

Cómo se describe [en este fantástico proyecto](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670115/Specification-pattern-in-Csharp) y viendo tu código veo que ya aplicas todos los patrones necesarios, por lo que te pongo un ejemplo de su utilización:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Mobile> mobiles = new List<Mobile> { 
            new Mobile(BrandName.Samsung, Type.Smart, 700), 
            new Mobile(BrandName.Apple, Type.Smart), 
            new Mobile(BrandName.Htc, Type.Basic), 
            new Mobile(BrandName.Samsung, Type.Basic) };

        ISpecification<Mobile> samsungExpSpec =
           new ExpressionSpecification<Mobile>(o => o.BrandName == BrandName.Samsung);
        ISpecification<Mobile> htcExpSpec =
           new ExpressionSpecification<Mobile>(o => o.BrandName == BrandName.Htc);
        ISpecification<Mobile> SamsungHtcExpSpec =  samsungExpSpec.Or(htcExpSpec);        
        ISpecification<Mobile> NoSamsungExpSpec = 
          new ExpressionSpecification<Mobile>(o => o.BrandName != BrandName.Samsung);

        var samsungMobiles = mobiles.FindAll(o => samsungExpSpec.IsStatisfiedBy(o));
        var htcMobiles = mobiles.FindAll(o => htcExpSpec.IsStatisfiedBy(o));
        var samsungHtcMobiles = mobiles.FindAll(o => SamsungHtcExpSpec.IsStatisfiedBy(o));
        var noSamsungMobiles = mobiles.FindAll(o => NoSamsungExpSpec.IsStatisfiedBy(o));
    }
}
```

Además en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16883638/1468942) del SO original puenen un ejemplo más reducido.